# C++ SDL2 Get Mouse Coordinates Without Delay

Tags: c++, mouseevent, mouse, sdl, sdl-2

I am making a **2D bird's-eye view shooter** with **C++** using the **SDL2** library in **Code::Blocks**, compiled with **MinGW**, running on **Windows 7**.

Everything is going along smoothly, but I've encountered one major problem and I have not been able to find any working solution. Being a shooter, the mouse is involved A LOT, but I can never return the mouse position at the exact right frame... It always seems to be around 2-5 frames behind.

For example, I need a cross hair image to always be on the (invisible) mouse. I know I could just use one of the Mouse functions like CreateCursor, but I still need accurate coordinates so that the aim is not off.  I'm using a basic script *like* this:

```
bool quit = false;
SDL_Event e;
int xMouse, yMouse;

while(quit == false)
{
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
    {
        if(e.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION)
        {
            SDL_GetGlobalMouseState(&xMouse,&yMouse);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if I had a cross hair image rendered at (xMouse-10, yMouse-10) *(subtraction used for origin)*, it will always trail behind the cursor. Also, the coordinates will take a couple frames to stop moving once the mouse has already stopped moving.

Offer me a better method of precise mouse tracking.

P.S. I am pretty new to C++ and SDL, so offer any miscellaneous advice if you would like to.

Comment: What OS are you using? It could be related to [this](http://blog.gsmarena.com/microsoft-fixes-gaming-mouse-lag-in-windows-8-1/) if you are using Windows 8.0.

Comment: Have you tried calling `SDL_GetGlobalMouseState(&xMouse,&yMouse);` without checking for a SDL_MOUSEMOTION event? So just get the mouse position in every execution of your main loop and check if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @lmNt I have tried this, still a delay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bit of a long shot, but on my Linux SDL2 project I had similar mouse lag, which was caused by setting the SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC flag on my renderer. Removing that flag fixed the lag. Might be worth trying.